# Crear una nueva variable en un dataframe que enumera cuenta el número de veces de una determinada condición

Tags: r, dataframe

Muy buenas tengo un data frame con solo variables. Aquí una versión recortada

```
 ID    Score
 Aje     1
 Aje     0
 Mem     1
 Mem     0
 Tet     1
 Tet     1
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es crear una nueva variable en el dataframe (IT) que el primer caracter sea siempre "I" y el segundo el número de veces que una determinada ID ha aparecido. Por ejemplo:

```
 ID    Score   IT
 Aje     1     I1
 Aje     0     I2
 Mem     1     I1
 Mem     0     I2
 Tet     1     I1
 Tet     1     I2
 Tet     0     I3
```

Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Deberias adjuntar el codigo que tienes hasta el momento para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 1):

Al final he encontrado una solución bastante fácil con data.table

```
 data= data.table(data)
 data[ , IT := 1:.N , by ="id",]
```

Answer (score 0):

Con R base una forma sencilla sería:

```
df$IT <- paste0('I',sequence(rle(df$ID)$lengths))
```

Con `rle` obtenemos cada conjunto contiguo de `ID` y las longitudes de cada uno de ellos, con `sequence()` generamos una secuencia según cada longitud